# Create a GO struct only if a certain condition is satisfied

Tags: go

My GO code snippet is as follows:

```
type MyStruct struct {
   a int
}

if a == nil {
        cond = 0
        var A_mystruct_obj MyStruct  // If this condition is satified then ONLY create this A_mystruct_obj obj
    } else if b == nil {
        cond = 1
        var B_mystruct_obj MyStruct  // If this condition is satified then ONLY create this B_mystruct_obj obj

    } else {
        cond = 2 // // If this condition is satified then create BOTH the above structure objects  A_mystruct_obj & B_mystruct_obj.
         // Is having the below declaration again in else a valid GO code ?
        var A_mystruct_obj MyStruct
        var B_mystruct_obj MyStruct
    }
```

I'm from a C++ background. This would have been simple in C++. Do we have dynamic memory allocation in GO. And how do I achieve this in GO ?

Is having the 2 declaration again in else a valid GO code ?

```
    var A_mystruct_obj MyStruct
    var B_mystruct_obj MyStruct
```

Or do I need to have some sort of run time polymorphism here.

**Updated:**

I tried doing this way, but it didn't even compile as expected.

https://go.dev/play/p/ioQ81aeXGjN

**Updated Again**

I tried this and it seems to work. Is this fine ?

https://go.dev/play/p/R_ywzmkgRpS

Comment: Sure, Go has dynamic memory allocation. I believe, you would make a pointer `MyStruct *` in C++ for that purpose?

Comment: yes. Wondering how to achieve this in GO ?  @bereal

Comment: Have you gone through the tour of Go? The chapter on pointers covers all of this. Start here https://go.dev/tour/welcome/1 see here https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/1

Comment: I did go thru the GO pointers. But unable to draw analogy with C++/other conventional OOPs languages. In C++, its as simple as we create a MyStruct* pointer outside the if else and in each if else, I can use a new() to create an instance of the object.  Wondering if similiar thing can be done in GO. 
var ptr *MyStruct -- Outside
Inside if /else, can I do:
ptr = new(MyStruct).

Will these 2 ptrs be the same ?

Comment: I tried doing it this way and it doesn't even compile saying obj created but not used:
https://go.dev/play/p/ioQ81aeXGjN

Comment: Something like this? https://go.dev/play/p/UCPjdm-8d24

Comment: I tried this way and this seems to work. Is it fine ? 
https://go.dev/play/p/R_ywzmkgRpS

Here i did it without using pointers.

Comment: @Peter This looks interesting. What do you think about my solution without pointers ?
go.dev/play/p/ioQ81aeXGjN

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual goal is. I was under the impression that you just want to avoid allocations, which using pointers does while also making the values available outside of the if-else-statement. Your code has minimal allocations too, but it also doesn't do anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems in your code:

1. your variables are declared within an enclosing scope, making them unreachable from outside that scope (the `if`/`else` clauses)
2. your variables are declared as values

The second problem arises when you address the first, i.e by moving your variable declarations outside of the `if` clause scopes, to make them accessible to code following the `if` statement:

```golang
    var A_mystruct_obj MyStruct
    var B_mystruct_obj MyStruct
    if a == nil {
        cond = 0
        // initialise A_mystruct
    } else if b == nil {
        cond = 1
        // initialise B_mystruct
    } else {
        cond = 2
        // initialise A_mystruct and B_mystruct
    }
```

Now both variables are declared but also both variables are initialised with a newly allocated `MyStruct`, regardless of which clause in the `if` statement is reached.

To solve *that* problem, change the variables to pointers and allocate the values required in the corresponding branch of the `if` statement:

```golang
    var A_mystruct_obj *MyStruct
    var B_mystruct_obj *MyStruct
    if a == nil {
        cond = 0
        A_mystruct_obj = &MyStruct{}
    } else if b == nil {
        cond = 1
        B_mystruct_obj = &MyStruct{}
    } else {
        cond = 2
        A_mystruct_obj = &MyStruct{}
        B_mystruct_obj = &MyStruct{}
    }
```

**Bonus tip:** *Future You* will thank you for refactoring this to a pair of statements that determine whether `a` is required or `b` or both and then simplifying your compound `if` statement as two *separate* statements that initialise an `a` or `b` respectively:

```golang
    var A_mystruct_obj *MyStruct
    var B_mystruct_obj *MyStruct

    areq := a == nil || (..condition 2..) 
    breq := b == nil || (..condition 2..) 
    if areq {
        A_mystruct_obj = &MyStruct{}
    }
    if breq {
        B_mystruct_obj = &MyStruct{}
    }
```

The intent being to avoid repetition of logic (the DRY principle: *Don't Repeat Yourself*) and separation of concerns.  i.e. separating the question of *whether* `a` and/or `b` *are required* from the process of initialising `a` and `b` *when* they *are* required.

NOTE: It isn't possible to be more specific as to how to express `condition 2` as it is not clear from your posted code what that condition is.

Comment: Regarding the first part of your answer wherein you mentioned that the variables declared inside the if else will have limited scope. I have a query with respect to this. 
Will this still be true if I declare these variables inside the if else statement to start with uppercase which will make its visibility outside of the he if else statement.
this brings to a fundamental golang related question that by making the first character of a variable name in uppercase, does it extend its scope outside of such if else  constructs or is it only limited to inside and outside a package.

Comment: No, exported vs non-exported applies only to package-level declarations and struct fields.  Local variables are local; a local variable introduced in a scope may be accessed from a nested (inner) scope but cannot be accessed from a nesting (outer) scope, regardless of the case of the initial letter of the variable name.